Customising a GGridges Plot in R
I'd like to create a ggridges-style plot with a few customisations.
I have a dataset with three variables:

a likert-like response variable (0:6 responses) called 'RankVar'
a node variable (1:9) called 'Node' (this captures a node assignment from a self-organising map).
and a cluster variable (A:C) called 'Clus'

In this regard, the response variable is characterised by a node ID and a cluster ID. For example, RankVar responses in Cluster A is characterised by a node ID = 1-4-5 out of the 9 nodes.
In terms of the customised ggridges plot, I'd like to:

stack the ridges conditional on cluster labels. Therefore, cluster A should have Node 1-4-5, and have the response variable on the x-axis.

I'd also like a blank space in between each cluster. Therefore, after cluster A with node 1-4-5, I'd like a space break (about a binwidth) prior to where cluster B begins node 2-3-7.

I'd also like each cluster to be indexed with its own colour. Therefore, nodes 1-4-5 having a different colour on the plot from Nodes 2-3-7.


I've attached my visual (without customisation) and the script that generated it. All help would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you in advance
##################################
#MY RIDGES SO FAR 
###################################

library(tidyverse)
library(ggplot2)
library(ggridges)
library(hrbrthemes)

#######################
#Creating the Ranked Response Variable 
#########################

RankVar = rep(0:5, times = 108) 
RankVar <- sample(RankVar)
RankVar <- as.factor(RankVar)

###############################################
# CREATING NODE ID TO BE ASSIGNED TO EACH OF THE 9 NODES
################################################

Node = rep(1:9, times = 72)
Node <- sample(Node)
Node <- as.factor(Node)

###############################################
#Creating Cluster ID
###############################################

Clus <- rep(LETTERS[1:3], times = 216)
Clus <- noquote(Clus)
Clus

###################
#DATA FRAME
####################

DAT <- data.frame(RankVar, Node)

##############################
#CLUSTER ASSIGNMENTS
##############################

DAT %>% 
  mutate(CLUS = case_when(Node == 1 | Node == 4 | Node == 5 ~ 'A', 
                         Node == 2 | Node == 3 | Node == 7 ~ 'B', 
                         Node == 6 | Node == 8 | Node == 9 ~ 'C'))

#######################################
#VISUALISATION WITHOUT REQUIRED CUSTOMISATION
########################################

ggplot(DAT, aes(x = RankVar, y = Node, fill = Node, group = Node)) +
  geom_density_ridges(alpha = .7, stat = "binline", bins = 30, scale = 0.9) +
  theme_ipsum(axis_title_size = 10) + 
  theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5, size = 12, face = "bold"),
        axis.text = element_text(size = 11), legend.position = "none") +
  labs(title = '') +
  scale_x_discrete() +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("#08519C","#08519C", "#08519C", 
                               "#08519C", "#08519C","#08519C", 
                               "#08519C", "#08519C","#08519C" ))



Is this what you're looking for?  If so, you can do most of what you need by faceting on CLUS and using fill=CLUS in the aesthetic.  The spacing between panels is controlled by the panel.spacing argument in theme().
library(tidyverse)
library(ggplot2)
library(ggridges)
library(hrbrthemes)
#######################
#Creating the Ranked Response Variable 
#########################

RankVar = rep(0:5, times = 108) 
RankVar <- sample(RankVar)
RankVar <- as.factor(RankVar)

###############################################
# CREATING NODE ID TO BE ASSIGNED TO EACH OF THE 9 NODES
################################################

Node = rep(1:9, times = 72)
Node <- sample(Node)
Node <- as.factor(Node)

###############################################
#Creating Cluster ID
###############################################

Clus <- rep(LETTERS[1:3], times = 216)
Clus <- noquote(Clus)


###################
#DATA FRAME
####################

DAT <- data.frame(RankVar, Node)

##############################
#CLUSTER ASSIGNMENTS
##############################

DAT <- DAT %>% 
  mutate(CLUS = case_when(Node == 1 | Node == 4 | Node == 5 ~ 'A', 
                          Node == 2 | Node == 3 | Node == 7 ~ 'B', 
                          Node == 6 | Node == 8 | Node == 9 ~ 'C'))

ggplot(DAT, aes(x = RankVar, y = Node, fill = CLUS, group = Node)) +
  geom_density_ridges(alpha = .7, stat = "binline", bins = 30, scale = 0.9) +
  theme_ipsum(axis_title_size = 10) + 
  theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5, size = 12, face = "bold"),
        axis.text = element_text(size = 11), 
        legend.position = "none", 
        panel.spacing = unit(1, "lines"),
        strip.text = element_text(hjust=.5)) +
  labs(title = '') +
  scale_fill_brewer(palette="Blues") + 
  facet_grid(CLUS~., scales="free_y")


Created on 2024-04-16 with reprex v2.0.2

Hi @DaveArmstrong. Thank you very much. That is the one, yes. Thank you again. May I ask how to customise the colours, such as with Blues from RColorBrewer, and if it is possible to centre the A-B-C label, such that they're on the node lines, 4, 3, 8?

@EB3112 just updated the answer.  You can use scale_fill_brewer(palette="Blues") to get the blues palette from RColorBrewer and you can use strip.text=element_text(hjust=.5) in theme() to centre the labels.

One final question @DaveArmstrong (promise). May I ask if it is possible to have the node axis as ascending? So, (1,4,5); (2,3,7), (6,8,9)?

If you do DAT <- DAT %>% mutate(Node = factor(Node, levels=9:1)), then the Nodes will print in ascending order within each group,

Hi @DaveArmstrong. Broke my promise, obviously. Would you know how to pivot the RHS 1,2,3 labels such that they're in the same upright direction as the LHS node axis, please?

Apologies. Got it: strip.text.y.right = element_text(hjust=.5, angle = 0))
